# show () o hide () element si el precio de un producto es menor o mayor

Tags: jquery, array, show, hide, selector

tengo la siguiente lading page

https://edg.wnpower.host/lumi/tienda/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde necesito hacer que se visualize un objeto (envio gratis) si el precio sea superior o inferior en cada una de las cajas de los artículos.

Son varios selectores que tengo que capturar como este, donde la clase "post-" varia:

```
 article.post-1829>div>div:nth-child(4)>div:nth-child(2)>ins>span>bdi
```

y probe algo como esto en la consola:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('div>div:nth-child(4)>div:nth-child(2)>ins>span>bdi')
```

Me devuelve los objetos que me interesan. A esos necesito aplicar una regla para obtener un valor numérico, algo similar a esto:

```
jQuery(function(jQuery) {
    var price = jQuery('article[class^="post-"]>div>div:nth-child(4)>div:nth-child(2)>ins'),
        priceValue = Number(price.text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")),
        priceLimit = 1000,
        shipping = jQuery("#shipp_emi");

    if (priceValue > priceLimit) {
        shipping.show();
    } else {
        shipping.hide();
    }
});
```

Espero se entienda la pregunta, gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Comment: gracias @ffflabs !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo creo que lo mejor sería manejarlo con clases. Tu sitio tiene la clase hidden de manera que en vez de `jQuery('#elemento').hide()` y `jQuery('#elemento').show()` debieses hacer `document.querySelector('#elemento').classList.add('hidden')` y `classList.remove('hidden')`.

Respecto de la pregunta misma, acá le añadí unas clases que juegan con el padding y color de fondo, dado que por css no puedo hacer visible el camioncito. De paso, tus camioncitos tienen el mismo atributo ID, eso es un error y lleva a comportamientos inconsistentes.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('article .w-vwrapper .woocommerce-Price-amount')].forEach(div=>{
   if(div.parentNode.tagName==='DEL') {
       return; // precio tachado
   }
 let priceDiv=div.querySelector('bdi');
   if(!priceDiv) {
      return; // caso de borde?
   } 
   let price=  (priceDiv.textContent.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g,''));  console.log( price); 
       let shippingDiv = div
                .parentNode
                .parentNode
                .parentNode
                .querySelector('.usg_html_1'); // elemento padre del camión

   if(!shippingDiv) { 
      return; // otro caso de borde?
   }
   // Si el camióncito tiene ID se lo quito para que no lo esconda el theme
   if(shippingDiv.querySelector('#shipp_emi')){
      shippingDiv.querySelector('#shipp_emi').removeAttribute('id');
   }

   if(price>3500) {
       shippingDiv.classList.remove('hidden')
   } else {
       shippingDiv.classList.add('hidden')
   }
});
```

Ahí puse el precio de envío gratis en 3500.

Fíjate que todos tus camioncitos tienen el mismo ID. Y además en cada recuadro hay un css que lo hace invisible.

```
 <div class="w-html usg_html_1">
    <style>
    .layout_2402 .usg_product_field_4 {
        color: #4CAF50!important;
        background: transparent;
        text-align: center!important;
        font-weight: 700!important;
        text-transform: uppercase!important;
        white-space: nowrap;
        font-size: 10px!important;
        padding-left: 0!important;
        padding-right: 0.8rem!important;
    }
        
    #shipp_emi {display:none}

    </style>

    <div id="shipp_emi" class="usg_product_field_4">
        <i class="fas fa-truck"></i> Envío gratis</div>
</div>
```

Lo que hice en mi script fue quitarles el ID para poder controlar su visibilidad con la clase `hidden`.

Comment: Gracias @ffflabs, no logro entender como implementar tu aporte, soy nuevo en esto. podrias indicarme como hacerlo y si debo modificar el codigo del camioncito, actualmente es : <div id="shipp_emi" class="usg_product_field_4"><i class="fas fa-truck"></i> Envío gratis</div>

Comment: en alguna parte de tu theme le está poniendo  estilo al camión que lo hace invisible . Edité el script y ahora es cosa que abras la consola del naveador  y pegues eso que puse

Comment: Gracias! lo pude ver perfecto, por alun motivo en el site de produccion no me funciona, www.lumilagro.com.ar/tienda/ hay algo diferente alli? gracias de verdad por tu ayuda!

Comment: los themes son distintos. El de producción no tiene el camioncito

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda fue muy importante! gracias!!!!

Comment: hola @ffflabs me da error la consola, quiza hay algo mal en el codigo? si bien funciona tengo ese error. probe comentar unas lineas pero persiste... hay algo que este haciendo mal? gracias!

Comment: solucionado, aparentemente todo bien.